# `includes?` in an array that may not be assigned

Tags: ruby, arrays

Is there a one-line way to use `include` if the array it's searching may not be assigned?

I've tried a lot of variants of

```
(foo || []).include?(:bar)
```

but without success

Comment: `foo = nil; (foo || []).include?(:bar)` should work, what's the problem?

Comment: Are you asking about something that's nil, in which case your code works just fine, or something that isn't even *assigned*?

Comment: @DaveNewton - thanks, you're right -- I meant if it's not even assigned

Comment: in what context do you need such an horrendous programming practice as using non-defined variables?

Comment: @tokland To be fair, this happens in Rails partials with locals, although that doesn't seem to be the nature of this question.

Comment: @Dave: well, yes, partials is a common scenario for that pattern, though there are more elegant ways to deal with it (calling helpers that set the default locals, for example, instead of directly the partial).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `foo` really is `nil`, as opposed to undefined, then `(foo || []).include?(:bar)` will do what you want, however if `foo` is not set to anything yet, then you will get a `NameError` so we can check for that with a longer oneliner...

```
defined?(foo) ? (foo || []).include?(:bar) : false
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(foo ||= []).include?(:bar)
```

That will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
foo.includes? :bar if foo
```

Comment: I may have misinterpreted the question; I was assuming it wasn't even assigned, not just `nil`--if it's assigned and `nil` of course this will work. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using partials, put this on the top of your partial:

```
<% foo = [] unless local_assigns.has_key?(:foo) # for Arrays %>
<% foo = {} unless local_assigns.has_key?(:foo) # for Hashes %>
<% foo = "" unless local_assigns.has_key?(:foo) # for Strings %>
```

etc.

This is the proper way of checking if a variable used in a partial has been set at all.

In the views using the foo partial:

```
 <% render :partial => "foo", :locals {:a => 1, :foo => [2, 3, 4]} %>
 <% render :partial => "foo", :locals {:a => 1} %>
```

In the first case, the `foo` variable will be `[2,3,4]` in the foo partial.

In the second case, the `foo` variable will not be put in `local_assigns` and will thus be given a default value as per the code above.